# Cartesian product of javascript object with different types of values like string, object and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, cartesian-product

I am working on an assignment.
I have the following object form.

```
{
    name: "name here",
    skills:  [ "cash", "shares" ],
    subjects: 
    [ 
      {
        subName: "subject1",
            remark: ['remark1', 'remark2']
          },
      {
        subName: "subject2",
            remark: ['remark1', 'Hockey']
          }
    ]
}
```

I want to generate a Cartesian product of the properties so that the output is an array of the following form:

```
[
   { "name": "name here",  "skills":  "cash",   "subjects": {  "subName":    "subject1", “remark”: “remark2” }},
   { "name": "name here",  "skills":  "cash",   "subjects": {  "subName":    "subject1", “remark”: “remark1”  }},
   { "name": "name here",  "skills":  "cash",   "subjects": {  "subName":    "subject2", “remark”: “remark1” }},
   { "name": "name here",  "skills":  "cash",   "subjects": {  "subName":    "subject2",  “remark”: “Hockey” }},
   { "name": "name here",  "skills":  "shares",  "subjects": {  "subName":  "subject1",  “remark”: “remark1” }},
   { "name": "name here",  "skills":  "shares",  "subjects": {  "subName":   "subject1",  “remark”: “remark2” }},
   { "name": "name here",  "skills":  "shares",  "subjects": {  "subName":  "subject2",  “remark”: “remark1”   }},
   { "name": "name here",  "skills":  "shares",  "subjects": {  "subName":  "subject2",  “remark”: “Hockey”  }}
]
```

I have tried many of the algorithms(mentioned in other SO posts) and even tried to customize some of them, but still not much improvement.

I would really appreciate any kind of help in this. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @JonasW. I have tried the solutions given in the other SO posts like the following
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957972/cartesian-product-of-objects-in-javascript
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697737/cartesian-product-of-javascript-object-properties
I have put some conditions in their algorithms to differentiate between arrays and objects. But I am unable to figure out how to look out for deeper arrays or objects. Sorry I am not good with recursive approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a recursive function which separates all key/value pairs and build a new cartesian product by iterating the values, if an array with objects call `getCartesian` again and build new objects.

The referenced [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697737/cartesian-product-of-javascript-object-properties) does not work, because of the given arrays of objects which the linked answer does not respect.

```js
function getCartesian(object) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var temp = [];
        r.forEach(s =>
            (Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]).forEach(w =>
                (w && typeof w === 'object' ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
                    temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [k]: x }))
                )
            )
        );
        return temp;
    }, [{}]);
}

var data = { name: "name here", skills: ["cash", "shares"], subjects: [{ subName: "subject1", remark: ['remark1', 'remark2'] }, { subName: "subject2", remark: ['remark1', 'Hockey'] }] };

console.log(getCartesian(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```